# Changing multiple records taken from JSON in a tableView | Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

**I have a tableview that is being populated using the the following function called gettingJSON:**

```
private func gettingJSON() {

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://test/test/test"),
        let value = name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "name=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([structure].self,from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.removeSpinner()

            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()

}
```

**I also have multiple selections enabled within the tableView to with the checkmark accessory enabled as the following:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
```

The records being populated in tableView are coming from a mySQL database that is then turned into JSON. I would like the user to select multiple records from the tableView and have some data associated with the record change.

So I would like to change multiple records at once (specific ones that are selected.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, or set selected flag manual to your objects you want to change

Comment: Ok, but how can the records be actually sent on Swift’s side once records are selected

Comment: You see what I mean?

Comment: You want to select multiple values, tableView.allowMultipleSelection = true, func didSelectRowAt, will select you cells, to get paths use tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, change your data in didSelectRowAt if needed then reloadData

Comment: Should I use an http POST request x however many records were selected? I’m more interested in how the app will talk to JSON API

Comment: I don't know how your API works and what data in your response

Comment: I don’t fully understand the question. Are you trying to update the records in the MySQL database based on the selections?. So far you only visually selected the cells. I wouldn’t even call it a selection. It’s really just a display option that just happens to be a check mark. What are you specifically trying to change? Also Alexander showed you a function that is used with the table views editable mode feature which is not what you’re using so it won’t work for you based on your example. It will always give you an empty array.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I’m trying to do, I would like to update the records in the mySQL data based on the selections. I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Do you recommend any git projects or advise as to how this can be done?